# Kafka Connect Error --> groupId=connect-cluster-confluent] Node 2 was unable to process the fetch request with FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND

Tags: apache-kafka, connector

I am running Confluent Community 5.5.0 to run Connector. Kafka cluster is on 2.3 version.

On running connector we keep getting below error:

```
[2020-05-18 15:24:38,567] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-confluent-1, groupId=connect-cluster-confluent] Node 2 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1641780505, epoch=241): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler:403)
[2020-05-18 15:24:38,728] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-confluent-3, groupId=connect-cluster-confluent] Node 2 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=958339504, epoch=242): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler:403)
[2020-05-18 15:25:06,699] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-confluent-2, groupId=connect-cluster-confluent] Node 1 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=482952399, epoch=309): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler:403)
[2020-05-18 15:25:07,122] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-confluent-1, groupId=connect-cluster-confluent] Node 1 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=480541689, epoch=304): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler:403)
```

Comment: can you paste the error you are talking about? I can only see INFO logs in your question.

Comment: Sorry. It was only INFO Log, but was wondering what is reason for this message

Comment: I am getting this and I have no idea what could be causing it or even if it is a meaningful error.